# Data attribute doesn't change value on each iteration using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, search, custom-data-attribute

When performing a list search, on each iteration the keywords are not changing.
Keywords are added using data attributes in HTML Code(which is rendered from the database, so it changes li will have different keywords). So on each iteration, the keyword remains the same and the search is not working(My guess).

**JS Code**

```
 function search_card() {
        var input, filter, txtvalue, key;
        input = document.getElementById('txtsearch');
        filter = input.value.toLowerCase();  
        $('.product_card').each(function(){
            key = $('.ProductNameBlock').data('keywords');
            if (key.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                $('.product_card').css('display','');
            }
                else {
                $('.product_card').css('display','none');
                }         
        });              
    }
```

**keywords used**

- txtsearch - input id
- product_card - li class name
- ProductNameBlock - div class name where data-keywords are rendered`(<div class="ProductNameBlock" data-keywords="<%# Eval("KeyWords")%>">`(values from db)

Keywords can be of different values for each iteration
Eg: Data First, Data Collection, Featured Apps
I don't know the correct format. What do I do?

Comment: You need `key = $(this).find('.ProductNameBlock').data('keywords');` instead, `$('.ProductNameBlock')` matches all divs of that class. Next you need `$(this).css(...)` (again, you're hiding/showing *all* cards)

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks brother @ChrisG

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct method

```
function search_card() {
        var input, filter, txtvalue, key;
        input = document.getElementById('txtsearch');
        filter = input.value.toLowerCase();  
        $('.product_card').each(function(){
            key = $(this).find('.ProductNameBlock').data('keywords');
            if (key.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                $(this).css('display','');
            }
                else {
                $(this).css('display','none');
                }         
        });              
    }
```